# Can I use Lagrange Multipliers with inequality constraints?

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I had a problem: Maximize $f(\bf{x}) $ subject to the contraints $g_i(\bf{x})< b$

Can I still use Lagrange multipliers?  My text says that the constraints need to be equalities.

Comment: If it is a strict inequality, then no.

Answer (score 1):

You do want $\le$, not $<$, otherwise there is likely to be no maximum.
The generalization of Lagrange multipliers to allow inequality constraints is the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush-Kuhn-Tucker_conditions).